# In make, can we use $^ to get the dependency list for just the current rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've been learning make from the software carpentry tutorial ([make patterns](http://software-carpentry.org/v4/make/patterns.html)) and it says that we can use $^ to get the dependency list for our rule but have extra dependencies for our target by writing extra empty rules. For example

```
all:
    touch f1.txt f2.txt a.txt

result: a.txt

result: f*.txt
    @echo $^
```

I thought that this would print `f1.txt f2.txt` but instead I see `f1.txt f2.txt a.txt`. Am I missing something or is the tutorial wrong?

---

Clearly, I should have been explicit, in the example I run `make` to create the files for the test, then I run `make result` to get the result shown.

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly (without e.g. variables). There could be only one active recipe for each target, and by the time it executes all its dependencies are already merged into single dep list. This is why we use `$<` and not `$^` for `%.o: %.c` pattern rule - because they usually contain `.d` files in dep list.

Comment: I've edited my question just to clarify that I meant to say run `make all` before `make result`, since both responders seem confused over that point.

Comment: Well the best answer is by Keltar but he left that as a comment so I'll give it to one of the others.

Comment: I've left a comment on the tutorial page to point out the error.

Comment: I suddenly reminded the _Double-Colon Rules_ and updated my answer accordingly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem and what you would like to do but if you type just `make` it is like if you were typing `make all` because `all` is the first target and thus the default goal. It should create the 3 files (or update their last modification date if they already exist), echo the recipe and you should see:

```
touch f1.txt f2.txt a.txt
```

If you then type `make result` you should see the result of `@echo $^`, that is the list of all dependencies of `result`:

```
f1.txt f2.txt a.txt
```

It is absolutely normal as you declared them all as dependencies of `result`.

Finally, if you type `make result` before `make` or `make all` and if `a.txt` does not exist or if there is no file matching `f*.txt`, you will get an error because `make` needs `a.txt` and at least one file matching `f*.txt` to make `result` and it does not know how to make them.

I cannot imagine a use case where the behaviour you expected (`$^` being expanded as dependencies of the current rule only) would be useful, but if really you need this feature you can use the rather obscure *Double-Colon Rules* (DCR):

```
all:
    touch f1.txt f2.txt a.txt

result:: a.txt
    @echo $^

result:: f*.txt
    @echo $^
```

Note that if there is a DCR for a target, all rules of this target must also be DCR. Note also that all DCR must have a recipe. A DCR recipe is applied if one of the dependencies of **this** rule is newer than the target. If several DCR apply, they are executed in order of appearance in the `Makefile`. And finally, what you were interested in: the `$^` automatic variable logically expands as the dependencies of the particular DCR.

Comment: Yes, the tutorial that I referenced claims that `$^` returns only the dependencies declared in this single rule. It seems that is not actually true and the tutorial is misleading.

Comment: There's a use case given in the tutorial if you can't think of one.

Comment: I do not know which `make`  they are using but I suspect it is not GNU make. Moreover, I think there are better and working ways to handle their use case.

Comment: Well they specified that they were using GNU make in an earlier tutorial.

Comment: [Their statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=358&v=PYtaEeMGsX8) is wrong for GNU Make 3.81, 3.82, and 4.1; I haven't tried any other versions.

Comment: I added something about Double-Colon Rules to my answer. It may provide something similar to what robochat was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, `$^` refers to the prerequisites for the current *target,* not the current *rule.*

Also, the results you are reporting are not correct; for `make result` I get `` make: *** No rule to make target `f*.txt', needed by `result'.  Stop. `` like I very much expected.

Comment: However, I've just tried out wildcard expansion test and I'm not seeing what you see. Make seems to be expanding the file list just like I expected it would. There is also a whole section on wildcard expansion in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual).

Comment: Wildcard expansion uses the files that happen to exist on the file system. This can be tricky with chained rules.